# Prisma many to many relation

Tags: mysql, prisma

I need to have the `TeamHome` and `TeamAway` in `Teams` but I can't figure out how.

At first I was doing optimization using `createMany` but I can't use `createMany` and create an array of objects inside so I tried to work around the problem.

I'm using Prisma `v4.10.1`.

```
generator client {
    provider = "prisma-client-js"
    previewFeatures = ["clientExtensions"]
}

datasource db {
    provider = "mysql"
    ...
}

model Team {
    ...
    FixturesHome Fixture[]  @relation(name: "home", map: "Fixtures")
    FixturesAway Fixture[]  @relation(name: "away", map: "Fixtures")
    Fixtures     Fixture[]  @relation(name: "FixtureTeams")
    ...
}

model Fixture {
    ...
    TeamHome   Team?       @relation(onDelete: Cascade, fields: [teamHomeId], references: [id], name: "home")
    teamHomeId Int?
    TeamAway   Team?       @relation(onDelete: Cascade, fields: [teamAwayId], references: [id], name: "away")
    teamAwayId Int?
    Teams      Team[]      @relation(name: "FixtureTeams")
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, your many to many relation has no join table. Any many to many relation requires a separate join table, for example "FixturesOnTeams" model which contains a compound primary key of both the primary keys of Fixture and Team.

Prisma shows an example here : https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-schema/relations/many-to-many-relations

Secondly, I question whether you need the away team and home team modelled in two separate relations. This is something that can be added as a field on the Team model. You could create a compound primary key on teamId and type (? you decide what field name is suitable here) and put all away teams and home teams into one relationship. You are complicating the design of your DB model by trying to put logic into the design of your model. This type of logic should be something you query for, not embed into the design of your table.

```
model FixturesOnTeams {
  teamId     Int                 @id @default(autoincrement())
  teamType   String
  Team       @relation(fields: [teamId, teamType], references: [id, type])
  fixtureId  Int
  Fixture    @relation(fields: [fixtureId], references: [id])

  @@id([teamId, teamType, fixtureId])
}

model Team {
  id         Int                 @unique
  type       String
  Fixtures   FixturesOnTeams[]

  @@id([id, type])
}

model Fixture {
    id         Int                 @id @default(autoincrement())
    Teams      FixturesOnTeams[]      
}
```

Comment: I don't see how specifying the the "home" or "away" in Team in my answer doesn't  model what you want. In the above schema, you can have Teams with type "Home" in FixturesOnTeams (your join table) and Teams with type "Away" in FixturesOnTeams. You can have the same team be of type both "home" or "away" by having two records with same teamID in FixturesOnTeams with type "Home" and "Away". My original answer was actually incorrect in that the join table didn't contain the compound key. I edited the answer.

Comment: Thank you John, but I need the `TeamHome` and `TeamAway` in `Fixture` since a team can be in many fixtures and be home for one and away for another, specifying the type in `Team` is not an option I'm afraid.

I need to get the team's fixtures where the team is home or away, and the team's fixtures all combined.